# how to separate date?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

In a database

```
  Date

 5/29/2013
 12/4/2013
 12/1/2014
```

The output will be like this

```
 Year   Month  date
 2013    5      29
 2013    12      4
 2014    12      1
```

I tried this code:

```
select [Date],
right([Date],4)  as year ,
left([Date],CHARINDEX('/',[Date])-1) as month ,
substring([Date],3,2) as date  
FROM Table1
```

but it not showed the result properly.

Comment: Is date a varchar column?

Comment: yes the column datatype is varchar.

Comment: are you in control of the format  of the content of that field? are you sure that the date format is m/d/y 100% of the time? what you mean exactly with ' it not showed the result properly'? beware that sql is not a presentation tool so you cannot and will never have a perfect formatting.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @datevar varchar(50) = '10/10/2014'
declare @date datetime = convert(date,@datevar,101)
SELECT datepart(year, @date) AS 'year'
    ,DATEPART(month, @date) AS 'Month'
    ,DATEPART(day, @date) AS 'Day'
```

you can use this also.

Comment: Yay. [`CONVERT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187928.aspx) called with no *style* parameter and an ambiguous date format (e.g. `2014/10/09` might be interpreted as 9th October or 10th September)

Comment: `101` is the correct format for the examples in the question, so would +1 for that, but it is of course an incorrect format for the example date in your answer. `111` would be more appropriate for that, but I'd suggest changing your example date to match the ones in the question rather than changing the *style*.

Comment: yes, that's valid point. @Damien_The_Unbeliever. updated answer as per question's example.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
select 
    Year(CONVERT(Datetime, [Date])) [Year],
    Month(CONVERT(Datetime, [Date])) [Month],
    Day(CONVERT(Datetime, [Date])) [Date]
FROM Table1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT DATEPART(yyyy,date) AS Year,
DATEPART(mm,date) AS Month,
DATEPART(dd,date) AS Day,
FROM Table1
```

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datepart.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
create table #t(id varchar(10))
insert into #t values('5/29/2013'),
 ('12/4/2013'),
 ('12/1/2014')

 select year(id) as [year],month(id) as [month],day(id) as [day] from #t
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this too :

```
select datepart(year,[Date]) [year], 
       datepart(month,[Date]) [month],
       datepart(day,[Date]) [day]
  FROM table1
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing so Just do as written below

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE,[date]) ,
YEAR = DATEPART(YEAR , CONVERT(DATETIME, [date])),
MONTH = DATEPART(MONTH , CONVERT(DATETIME, [date])),
DAY = DATEPART(DAY, CONVERT(DATETIME, [date]))
FROM DateTable
```

You can also use other formats if your data is not in this format

Answer (score 0):

As Date is a varchar column, first convert it to DateTime and then do the manipulations as :

```
SET DATEFORMAT MDY;

select [Date],
       cast ([Date] as Datetime),
       Year(cast ([Date] as Datetime)) [Year],
       Month(cast ([Date] as Datetime)) [Month],
       Day(cast ([Date] as Datetime)) [Date]
FROM Table1
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://rextester.com/JBJV72085)</kbd>